# How do I return json in a psycopg2 query?

Tags: python, json, postgresql-9.2, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 (version 2.5.4) to query a PostgreSQL database (version 9.2.7).  One of the columns I'm querying is a json type which psycopg2 is documented as being able to handle.  However, I'm receiving the following error:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: could not identify an equality operator for type json

I'm not performing any equality operations on the column in question, just returning it with a select statement.  The query is simple and fairly straight forward:

```
SELECT DISTINCT me.measure_id, me.choices  
FROM measures ME  
WHERE TRUE AND me.measure_id IN (3)  
ORDER BY me.measure_id;
```

me.choices is the only column of type JSON in the table.  I've searched extensively and found nothing and can't think of a way forward.  Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Would it throw an error if you would replace `me.choices` with `me.choices::text`?

Comment: @alecxe That works for this use case.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select distinct` requires that each full row be distinct. So when you say `select DISTINCT me.measure_id, me.choices` you're asking postgresql to perform equality operations on `choices` to see if two rows are the same.

Assuming `measure_id` is the primary key for `measures` you can drop the `distinct`. Otherwise you could use [`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) to grab just one row for a `measure_id`.

Comment: Thank you.  Your suggestion worked.  I kept looking in my python code for someplace where I did an equality operation on that and it just didn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Somehow only noticed this comment just now. For future reference, psycopg2's ProgrammingError is thrown when postgres returns an error. So any time you see a ProgrammingError you can infer the error arose in the database, not in your program code. Sort of a confusing name, IMO.